# Is there any way to show the format of input text to user like ___/__/__?

Tags: android, format, android-edittext, textinput

I have an EditText in my Activity that users must enter date in it in my desired format like `____/__/__`. Is there any way to show this format in EditText of Android like mask textboxes of some programming languages?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not keep three separate textbox with the `/` in between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.setHint("____/__/__");
```

OR

```
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="____/__/__"/>
```

EDIT

I would recommend a `DatePicker` though rather than having users enter numbers and slashes. If `DatePicker` is not an option, I would then recommend 3 EditTexts that each have their own hint and which possibly automatically move between each other when they reach their automatic size.

```
[2012]/[01]/[01]
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. Is there any way that hint keeps its format during entering the text?

Comment: What do you mean? The text isn't forced to be in that format if that's what you're asking.

Comment: When you are entering the text, the hint string is made invisible. Is it possible to keep it visible?

Comment: No it's not possible to do that, AFAIK. Although as I mention above, you're asking for trouble if you have users enter dates that way. I would recommend using a DatePicker and then using it's methods to get the date in whatever format you'd like.

Comment: I can not use DatePicker because my users' calendar is not Gregorian Calendar and have their own local calendar :(

Comment: @breceivemail I think the 3 EditTexts would work best for you, did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

You could do separate Edittexts with textviews of "/" between them and then concatenate them...